# Thymeleaf parse text and execute in-text expressions

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

I have text string, that contains links, for example, like `<a th:href="'someLink'">Download</a>` .

I need to process that text and replace `th:href="'someLink'"` with correct links to show text with `<a href="someLink">Download</a>`.

The text with links is stored in variable **textThatContainsLinks**.

My code to show text is `<div th:utext="${textThatContainsLinks}">`. I also tried to use preprocessing like `<div th:utext="${__textThatContainsLinks__}">`.

Currently this code shows links not as I expected, but non-preprocessed, ie, output is `<a th:href="'someLink'">Download</a>` now.

How to pre-process expressions in text, before showing it?

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why can't you write <a th:href="${textThatContainsLinks}">Download</a>

Comment: Write where? In variable, that contains HTML, that contains `th:` expressions?

Comment: Ok, I think I got it now what you want to do. Is the textThatContainsLinks an array of such anchor elements?

Comment: The text with links is stored in variable textThatContainsLinks. Ie, this is variable with HTML, that contains links, that could be same to `<a th:href="'someLink'">Download</a>`

Answer (score 0):

Take the context path and directly attach it to the relative path of a pure html5 attribute e.g `<a href="/contextPath/relative/path">LINK</a>`, `<img src="/contextPath/relative/path/image.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="logo"/>`. 
Notice how simple the accessibility to the resource is: `/contextPath/relativePath`, so the most important path there is the relative path. This is similar to [Thymeleaf was unable to render `<img>` tag when sent from database table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444058/thymeleaf-was-unable-to-render-img-tag-when-sent-from-database-table). I observed that once thymeleaf's namespace `th:` qualifies a `href` or `src` attribute that resides inside a text/String the absolute path is not properly resolved.