# Thymeleaf was unable to render <img> tag when sent from database table

Tags: thymeleaf

Why is thymeleaf not rendering

```
<img th:src="@{/path/img/logo.jpg}" width="50" height="50" alt="logo"/>
```

when it is read from a database table and placed on a page as an unescaped text (`th:utext`)?

Ordinarily when placed on the page, it renders properly.
The idea is to save an uploaded image to a path in the application and save the name of the image as a string in the database table. During reading of the image, the name is gotten from the database table and placed in the `<img>`     tag. This works well with JSP's but I am unable to get similar result with thymeleaf. I checked my brower console log and the path `th:src="@{/path/img/logo.jpg}"` is visible but not parsed as to display the image on the page.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Share some code here to have a better understanding what's going on.

Comment: @NAVIN: I did share the code in the question. The string coming from the database table has in it `<img th:src="@{/path/img/logo.jpg}" width="50" height="50" alt="logo"/>` but when rendered on the page, the image tag is not rendering even though the relative path is correct.  @piet.t: thanks for editing my question, I am just getting a hang on this now, I appreciate, the editing was perfect to say the least.

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a solution. I attached the context path to the relative path of the `src` attribute without thymeleaf's namespace qualification like so: `<img src="/contextPath/path/img/logo.jpg" width="50" height="50" alt="logo"/>`. 
Notice how simple the accessibility to the resource is: `/contextPath/relativePath`, so the most important path there is the relative path. This is similar to: [Thymeleaf parse text and execute in-text expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46238304/thymeleaf-parse-text-and-execute-in-text-expressions/53452316#53452316).
I observed that once thymeleaf's namespace th: qualifies a `href` or `src` attribute that resides inside a text/String, the absolute path is not properly resolved.